# It is possible to Chaining this code in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

It is possivle chaining this code in jquery? or how I could improve?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul li:nth-child(2) .collapse-styled").addClass('in');
  $("ul li:nth-child(2) .collapse-link a").removeClass('collapsed');
});
```

Comment: You could certainly chain it, but it would become quite difficult to read. I'd suggest just caching the `ul li:nth-child(2)` selector and re-using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cannot chain both statements as the two elements are on separate branches from each other. BUT, I would suggest saving the `li` to shorten the search time like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $li = $("ul li:nth-child(2)");
  $li.find(".collapse-styled").addClass('in');
  $li.find(".collapse-link a").removeClass('collapsed');
});
```

Note:
Technically, you CAN chain them by going up the document tree but it would be highly inefficient. For example (if you have only one `li` parent):

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2) .collapse-styled").addClass('in').closest("li").find(".collapse-link a").removeClass('collapsed');
```

I reccoment you don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $listElement = $("ul li:nth-child(2)");
   $listElement.find(".collapse-styled").addClass('in');
   $listElement.find(".collapse-link a").removeClass('collapsed');
});
```